# SIGPROC in python

Tags: python, signal-processing

Sigproc is used to standardize the initial analysis of the many types of fast-sampled pulsar data. How and what should I do to install it on my windows.
Are there any alternative libraries that I can use?
[http://sigproc.sourceforge.net/#:~:text=Installing%20SIGPROC&text=and%20specify%20the%20location%20of,the%20compilation%20will%20proceed%20seamlessly](http://sigproc.sourceforge.net/#:%7E:text=Installing%20SIGPROC&text=and%20specify%20the%20location%20of,the%20compilation%20will%20proceed%20seamlessly)!

The documentation provided is a little vague about the details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have tagged this with "Python".  That program is written in C and Fortran, and compiles into a standalone executable.  It looks to be designed only for Linux systems.  We can't really advise you on alternatives, because we don't know what you are doing.